# c++ Linked list inserts a false node at start

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've been writing a program using a linked list, but for some reason my program is making a false node at the start of the program that is messing with everything else

this file controls the functions in the header file

```
Node *createNode() {

    Node *newNode = new Node;

    cout << "Enter in Students last Name" << endl;
    cin >> newNode->lastName;
    cout << "Enter in Students first Name" << endl;
    cin >> newNode->firstName;
    cout << "Enter in Students id" << endl;
    cin >> newNode->idNumber;

    return newNode;
}

Node *insertNode(Node *ptr) {

    Node *newNode = createNode();

    if( ptr == NULL ) {
        ptr = newNode;
    } else if ( ptr->idNumber > newNode->idNumber ) {
        newNode->next = ptr;
        ptr = newNode;
    } else {
       Node *temp = ptr;
       while( temp->next != NULL && 
              temp->next->idNumber < newNode->idNumber )
           temp = temp->next;
       if( temp->next == NULL ) {
           temp->next = newNode;
       } else {
            newNode->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = newNode;
       }
    }

    return ptr;
}

Node *searchNode(Node *ptr, int id) {

    Node *temp;
    Node *found;
    bool isfound = false;
    temp = ptr;

    if(temp == NULL) {
        cout << "There are no students in the list" << endl;
        isfound = true;
    }
    while( isfound != true && temp->next != NULL ) {
        if( temp->idNumber == id ) {
            found = temp;
            isfound = true;
            cout << found->lastName << ", " << found->firstName 
                 << ": " << found->idNumber << endl;

        } else {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    return found;
}


void printList( Node *ptr ){

    Node *temp = ptr;

    while( temp != NULL ) {
        cout << temp->lastName << ", " 
             << temp->firstName<< ": " 
             << temp->idNumber << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }    
}
```

and this is the main file where the program is executed

```
int main() {

    Node *list = new Node();
    displayList(list);

    return 0;
}

void displayList( Node *node ) {

    int option = -1;
    cout << node->idNumber << endl;

    while( option != 5 ) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
        cout << "1: Add a student" << endl;
        cout << "2: Search for student" << endl;
        cout << "3: Delete Student" << endl;
        cout << "4: Print Student List" << endl;
        cout << "5: Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a number for the choice: ";
        cin >> option;

        if( cin.fail() || option > 5 || option < 0 ) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            option = -1;
        }

        switch( option ) { 
            case 1:{
                insertNode(node);
            }
                break;
            case 2:{
                if(node != NULL){
                    cout<<"Enter the id you want to find: ";
                    int sid;
                    cin >> sid;
                    searchNode(node, sid);
                } else {
                    cout<<"No Ids in the list"<<endl;
                }
            }    
                break;
            case 4: printList(node);
                break;
            case 5: cout<<"GoodBye."<<endl ; 
                break;
            default: cout<<"you have entered a invalid character"<<endl;

        }
    }
}
```

this is what is being created before a new node is even created

```
What do you want to do?
1: Add a student
2: Search for student
3: Delete Student
4: Print Student List
5: Exit
Enter a number for the choice: 4
, : 0
```

Comment: Reduce the code to a bare minimum before posting here.

Comment: reduced as much as I can without leaving out something

Comment: There's no need to input anything, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Why not format the code so that it is readable?

Comment: Why do you provide a user Dialog when you just call for support in a set of functions that should be called in a predefined sequence to reproduce your Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Node *list = new Node();` since you created a new `Node` in main and passing a valid `Node` address to `displayList( Node *node );` and then to `printList( Node *ptr )`, its printing the zero initialized `Node` data.

You can change `Node *list = new Node();` to `Node *list = NULL` in `main()`

Remove `cout << node->idNumber << endl;` in `displayList( Node *node );` otherwise you will be getting segmentation fault or null dereferencing.

In `Node *createNode()`, add `newNode->next = 0;` you must set the `next` pointer of newly created `Node` to `NULL`.

In `Node *searchNode(Node *ptr, int id)` change `while( isfound != true && temp->next != NULL )` into `while( isfound != true && temp != NULL )`, otherwise it will not search the last node.

Store the return value of `insertNode(node)` to `node` in `displayList( Node *node );` as `node = insertNode(node)` otherwise you are loosing the newly added node for both the `if` and `else if` cases of `insertNode`